# Plotly Annotations are always showing on top of plot trace

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

```js
var trace2 = {
  x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  y: [0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2],
  type: 'scatter'
};
var layout = {
  showlegend: false,
  annotations: [
    {
      x: 2,
      y: 5,
      xref: 'x',
      yref: 'y',
      text: 'max=5',
      showarrow: false,
      bgcolor: '#ff7f0e',
      opacity: 1
    }
  ]
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv',  [trace2], layout);
```

```html
<head>
    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.27.0.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

I am facing an issue in showing annotations with border and fill color below the plot trace. Every time plot data is showing below annotation.

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJbNh.png)

My requirement is plot trace should be on top of annotations.

any solutions or tips to handle are most welcome.

Comment: please share the code!

Comment: var trace1 = {
  x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  y: [0, 1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 6, 5],
  type: 'scatter'
};
var trace2 = {
  x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  y: [0, 4, 5, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2],
  type: 'scatter'
};
var data = [trace1, trace2];
var layout = {
  showlegend: false,
  annotations: [
    {
      x: 2,
      y: 5,
      xref: 'x',
      yref: 'y',
      text: 'max=5',
      showarrow: false,
      align: 'center',
      borderwidth: 2,
      borderpad: 4,
      bgcolor: '#ff7f0e',
      opacity: 0.8
    }
  ]
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);

Comment: Hi, Kiran. You can edit your original question, and add the code there.